# Получение итогов на каждом уровне иерархического запроса MS SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть две таблички

```
DIRS
====
DIR_ID 
PARENT_DIR_ID
DIR_NAME

FILES
=====
FILE_ID
FILE_NAME
DIR_ID
FILE_SIZE
```

DIRS:

```
DIR_ID   PARENT_DIR_ID   DIR_NAME
======   =============   ========
1                        ROOT
2        1               DIR1_1
3        1               DIR1_2
4        2               DIR2_1
5        2               DIR2_2
```

FILES:

```
FILE_ID   FILE_NAME   DIR_ID   FILE_SIZE
=======   =========   ======   =========
1         test1.txt   5        100
2         test2.txt   5        200
3         test5.txt   5         50 
4         test3.txt   3        300
5         test4.txt   3        300
6         test6.txt   4        100
7         test7.txt   2        100
```

Как написать запрос чтоб результат был такой

```
Path                    File_Count
=====                   ===========
/ROOT                   7
/ROOT/DIR1_1            5
/ROOT/DIR1_1/DIR2_1     1
/ROOT/DIR1_1/DIR2_2     3
/ROOT/DIR1_2            2
```

Пытаюсь написать пример с оператором WITH RECURSIVE, но пока приемлемого варианта не получается. Может где-то мануал есть с подобным примером.

Comment: *Пытаюсь написать пример с оператором WITH RECURSIVE* Сообщение об ошибке синтаксиса - это хороший результат...

Comment: *Может где-то мануал есть с подобным примером.* [WITH common_table_expression (Transact-SQL)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2012/ms175972%28v%3dsql.110%29). Примеры - имеются.

Comment: Почему же сообщение об ошибке синтаксиса? В моей версии ms sql server только такая работает. По поводу мануала, я не увидел там примера как правильно собирать сумму чего либо при, например, обратном проходе по иерархии. Вывести уровень вложенности не проблема. А вот просуммировать записи от child к его parent я что то не могу

Comment: *Почему же сообщение об ошибке синтаксиса?* Ссылку на мануал я дал. Ищите, где там описывается токен RECURSIVE. *я не увидел там примера как правильно собирать сумму чего либо при, например, обратном проходе по иерархии* Да сперва получите хотя бы без суммирования, просто список в полными путями! Когда получите, останется засунуть такой запрос в CTE и сгруппировать. *просуммировать записи от child к его parent я что то не могу* Читайте справку про GROUP BY, особенно обращая внимания, нафига там WITH ROLLUP. Вдруг поможет. Ну или копите СOUNT(), собирая всё от листьев к корню. Или SUM() OVER.

Comment: может через xml xpath попробовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант, можно сделать в несколько шагов.
Сначала считаем пути и количество файлов в каждой папке. Грузим это во временную таблицу, а потом в цикле по уровням обновляем количество файлов начиная с листового уровня дерева иерархии. Может быть это и выглядит не очень красиво, но иногда такие топорные решения бывают вполне эффективными. Нужно смотреть по ситуации.

```
;WITH [DIRS] ([DIR_ID], [PARENT_DIR_ID], [DIR_NAME])
AS
(
    SELECT 1, NULL, N'ROOT'
     UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, 1, N'DIR1_1'
     UNION ALL
    SELECT 3, 1, N'DIR1_2'
     UNION ALL
    SELECT 4, 2, N'DIR2_1'
     UNION ALL
    SELECT 5, 2, N'DIR2_2'
)
,[FILES] ([FILE_ID], [FILE_NAME], [DIR_ID], [FILE_SIZE])
AS
(
    SELECT 1, N'test1.txt', 5, 100
     UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, N'test2.txt', 5, 200
     UNION ALL
    SELECT 3, N'test3.txt', 5, 50
     UNION ALL
    SELECT 4, N'test4.txt', 3, 300
     UNION ALL
    SELECT 5, N'test5.txt', 3, 300
     UNION ALL
    SELECT 6, N'test6.txt', 4, 100
     UNION ALL
    SELECT 7, N'test7.txt', 2, 100
)
-- Рекурсивным ОТВ склеиваем путь
,[CTE]
AS
(
    SELECT [DIRS].[DIR_ID]
          ,[DIRS].[PARENT_DIR_ID]
          ,[DIRS].[DIR_NAME]
          ,0 AS [Level]
          ,CAST(N'/' + [DIRS].[DIR_NAME] AS nvarchar(MAX)) AS [Path]
      FROM [DIRS]
     WHERE [PARENT_DIR_ID] IS NULL
     UNION ALL
    SELECT [DIRS].[DIR_ID]
          ,[DIRS].[PARENT_DIR_ID]
          ,[DIRS].[DIR_NAME]
          ,[CTE].[Level] + 1 AS [Level]
          ,[CTE].[Path] + N'/' + [DIRS].[DIR_NAME] AS [Path]
      FROM [CTE]
           INNER JOIN [DIRS]
           ON [CTE].[DIR_ID] = [DIRS].[PARENT_DIR_ID]
)
SELECT [CTE].[DIR_ID]
      ,[CTE].[PARENT_DIR_ID]
      ,[CTE].[Path]
      --Инвертируем нумерацию уровней вложенности папок
      ,DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY [CTE].[Level] DESC) AS [Level]
      -- Считаем количество файлов в папке
      ,(
           SELECT COUNT([FILES].[FILE_ID]) AS [File_Count]
             FROM [FILES]
            WHERE [CTE].[DIR_ID] = [FILES].[DIR_ID]
       ) AS [File_Count]
  INTO #Tmp --Выгружаем результат во временную таблицу
  FROM [CTE]

-- Объявляем и инициализируем переменную для счётчика
DECLARE @l int = 1

-- Запускаем бесконечный цикл, где проходим по всем уровням иерархии
WHILE (1=1)
BEGIN
    -- Вычисляем количество файлов для каждой родительской папки на текущем уровне иерархии
    ;WITH [CTE]
    AS
    (
        SELECT [PARENT_DIR_ID]
              ,SUM([File_Count]) AS [File_Count]
          FROM #Tmp
         WHERE [Level] = @l
         GROUP BY [PARENT_DIR_ID]
    )
    -- Обновляем количество файлов для папок родителей
    UPDATE #Tmp
       SET [File_Count] = #Tmp.[File_Count] + [CTE].[File_Count]
      FROM [CTE]
     WHERE [Level] = @l + 1 AND
           #Tmp.[DIR_ID] = [CTE].[PARENT_DIR_ID]

    -- Прерываем цикл, если закончились строки для обработки
    IF @@RowCount = 0
        BREAK;

    SET @l = @l + 1
END

-- Выводим результат
SELECT [Path]
      ,[File_Count]
  FROM #Tmp
 ORDER BY [Path]

-- Удаляем временную таблицу
IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#Tmp') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #Tmp
```

Comment: Спасибо, ваше решение интересное и правильное. Но по всей видимости я некорректно задал вопрос. Аналогичный результат можно получить без WITH? (Меня интересует самый быстрый вариант, дерево довольно большое, более 10.000 элементов). Можете что-то предложить еще?

Comment: Ну, рекурсивное CTE это довольно быстрый вариант. А индексы на таблицах есть? Типа таких:
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_FILES_DIR_ID] ON [FILES] ([DIR_ID])
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_DIRS_PARENT_DIR_ID] ON [DIRS] ([PARENT_DIR_ID]) INCLUDE ([DIR_NAME])